# ArcGIS SDO_GEORASTER BUG on Oracle 11g R2

Tags: arcgis, esri, raster, oracle11gr2

ESRI suggests not to use SDO_Georaster data type on Orcle 11g R2 for the following reson:
http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38940

We had ArcGIS 10.1 setup on Oracle 11g R2 and we are able to insert data into SDO_GEORASTER data type.

Is there anyone that experienced that bug¸or was able to reproduce it ?
it looks like no body talks about it on the web! I must be missing something here :/

Is it really a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I've solved the problem...

We are now able to insert data into SDO_GEORASTER without any problem using Oracle 11g R2 using the following geoprocessing tool:
Data Management Tools => Raster => Raster Dataset => Copy Raster

The regionnal settings of my ArcGIS Desktop computer was French Canadian. So ArcGIS was inserting comas as decimal separators in the raster metadata.
I've found this by using the following to SQL commands:

SDO_GEOR.validateGeoRaster() and SDO_GEOR.schemaValidate()

Last night ESRI support team that was helping me confirmed that Regional settings would be to workaround for this bug:

> Regarding the Oracle bug, it actually looks like Oracle has not adequately updated their bug database. Upon further investigation on our bug (NIM069549) that references the Oracle bug, there is an activity logged by one of the Esri Inc support staff. He mentions that he spoke to Oracle in May 2012, and that Oracle has actually closed this  Oracle incident (12537431) as NOT a bug. This analyst says that the reason given is because OCIEnvNlsCreate uses the national language setting of the computer (Nls = National Language Setting). OCIEnvNlsCreate is used when creating an sdo_georaster and the failure occurs when the Oracle xml document is created.
>
> Basically – the reason that users can experience this Oracle bug is
>   because of regional language settings in either the O/S or Oracle.
>
> We have spoken to Esri Inc and have requested that the following be
>   updated to reflect this finding from Oracle:
>
> NIM069549 - http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDY5NTQ5 NOTE:
>   have requested that the alternate solution be changed to state that it
>   can be caused by regional language settings. Also, reason for
>   rejection needs to be changed accordingly
>
> Error:  An Oracle LPX-0019 error occurs when inserting data into an
>   SDO_GEORASTER field
>   -http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38940 NOTE: have requested that the solution/workaround be changed to state
>   that it can be caused by regional language settings. Suggested to try
>   changing to English language setting.
>
> ArcGIS and the Oracle Spatial raster type -
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002n0000006z000000
>   NOTE: this is the article with the known limitations at the bottom.
>
> Since metadata is in XML format, it is quite possible that the commas
>   you were getting with the French language setting were directly
>   related to this issue. The Oracle XmlLoadDom function returns the
>   erorr, so you will see this error in Oracle, not in ArcMap.